Derivation of an integral based on an unknown function based on the integral equation that defines said function.
I am reading the book "Mathematical Constants" by Steven Finch. In section 8.5: Travelling Salesman Constants, he mentions the following result:

Krauth and Mézard [23] nonrigorously obtained an analytical expression for $\beta$ via the cavity method:
$$\beta = \frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)(1 + f(x))\exp(-f(x))\ dx = 2.0415\dots = 2(1.0208\dots),$$
where $f(x)$ is the solution of the integral equation
$$f(x) = \int_{-x}^{\infty} (1 + f(y))\exp(-f(y))\ dy$$

While the keyword is nonrigorously, I'm still puzzled. How did they evaluate the $\beta$, without even knowing a "concrete" closed-form formula of $f(x)$? I can't access the original paper, so any help would be appreciated!

In case it helps, $\beta=-\frac12\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)f'(-x),dx$.

@GregMartin how did you derive it? I'd assume you take $\frac{d}{dx}$ of both sides, but when I did it it doesn't lead me to anything.

The paper by Krauth and Mézard is freely available in https://www.researchgate.net/publication/230994052_The_Cavity_Method_and_the_Travelling-Salesman_Problem.

In the second equation $f(x)=\cdots$, I changed $x$ to $-x$ and then took derivatives of both sides; the resulting identity can be used to simplify the integrand in the first equation $\beta=\cdots$.

@Gonçalo thanks!
